# Changing MAC Address

Tags: mac-address, mac, mac-auth-bypass

On learning about MAC addresses i came across U/L bit in the first octet. Further on i learned that MAC address could be spoofed.

> If U/L bit switches according to MAC address modification , how could
>   someone change the MAC address to a specific valid one ?

example :

PC1 : MAC 04:11:11:11:11:11
PC2 : MAC 08:22:22:22:22:22

User tries to change PC2 MAC to 04:11:11:11:11:11 so U/L bit changes to 1 so MAC should be changing to 06:11:11:11:11:11

> Is U/L bit toggled by system or user ? Is it mandatory to change U/L
>   bit?

Comment: You’re assuming that the spoofer follows the rules.

Comment: could you explain the correct behavior in this scenario? does it  belong to the spoofer to choose whether to toggle U/L bit ?

Comment: There is no correct behavior. That’s the whole point of spoofing.

Comment: A thief doesn’t follow the rules either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the MAC address is stored in an EEPROM connected to the network controller. The driver by default reads the MAC address from the EEPROM and tells the network controller to use it. However most drivers offer a way to override this behaviour and use a user-specified MAC address.

The U/L bit is just a convention, intended to prevent conflicts if everyone is following the rules. It doesn't prevent deliberate spoofing.